# PostgreSQL - SELECT with two many2many relations

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, many-to-many, relational-database

**Context** : I have a table POST related to TAGS and CATEGORIES (all many2many relations). I want to return posts even if they don't have any TAGS or CATEGORIES, both in respective arrays.

**Example** :

```
 - POST1 with TAG1, TAG2 and CAT1  
 - POST2 WITH CAT3, CAT4, CAT5
 - POST3
```

I want to return :

```
 - POST1 / {TAG1, TAG2} / {CAT1}
 - POST2 / NULL / {CAT3, CAT4, CAT5}
 - POST3 / NULL / NULL
```

But I have :

```
 - POST1 / {TAG1, TAG2} / {CAT1, NULL, NULL}
 - POST2 / {NULL, NULL} / {CAT3, CAT4, CAT5}
 - POST3 / {NULL, NULL} / {NULL, NULL, NULL}
```

*If screenshot doesn't work, part of my code for relation :*

```
`FROM bmb_blog_post as post 
LEFT OUTER JOIN bmb_blog_category_bmb_blog_post_rel as posts_categories ON posts_categories.post_id = post.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN bmb_blog_category as category ON category.id = posts_categories.category_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN bmb_blog_post_bmb_blog_tag_rel as posts_tags ON posts_tags.post_id = post.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN bmb_blog_tag as tag ON tag.id = posts_tags.tag_id`
```

[PgAdmin SQL Results Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKjTH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then way is with two subqueries where you aggregate *before* doing the final joins:

```
SELECT p.id, pc.categories, pt.tags
FROM bmb_blog_post p LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT pc.post_id, array_agg(c.category) as categories
      FROM bmb_blog_category_bmb_blog_post_rel pc JOIN
           bmb_blog_category c
           ON c.id = pc.category_id
      GROUP BY pc.post_id
     ) pc
     ON pc.post_id = p.id LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     (SELECT pt.post_id, array_agg(t.tag) as tags
      FROM bmb_blog_post_bmb_blog_tag_rel pt JOIN
           bmb_blog_tag t
           ON t.id = pt.tag_id
      GROUP BY pt.post_id
     ) pt
     ON pt.post_id = p.id ;
```

Your results would be even more outlandish if you had posts that had multiple categories *and* multiple tags.

Comment: It works. The problem is I wanted to simplify my problem to ask help, and this solution doesn't work in the full context! I will post another question with the full problem. Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: @Olivb40 . . . I really appreciate your asking another question, rather than changing the current question and invalidating this answer.

Comment: Finally I succeeded with few changes thanks to you. I will post another question later for asking help about optimization of my FullText Search with PostgreSQL.